# Same Example for Two Counter Examples

Tags: probability, convergence

I'm learning some probability theory and I've come across the following:

For an example of a sequence of random vairables that converges in the mean square sense but not almost surely: We set
$$P(X_n=1) =1/n \qquad P(X_n=0)=1-1/n$$
and $X_n\to X$ in mean square but not almost sure. The not almost sure follows from the second Borel Cantelli Lemma.
I got the examples from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149775/convergence-of-random-variables-in-probability-but-not-almost-surely/149777)

However, in the book Counter Examples in Probability, they give the following example for a sequence that converges almost surely but not completely
$$Y_n(w) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
1 & 0\leq w< 1/n\\
0 & 1/n \leq w <n
\end{array}\right.$$

Don't $X_n$ and $Y_n$ define identical distributions? How does $X_n$ converse almost surely but $Y_n$ doesn't?

Comment: $X_n$ is only partially defined.  To see why that is, consider how you might compute (say) $\Pr((X_n, X_{n+1})=(1,1)).$  What would it be?

Comment: What do I need to define them further? I could say they are independent. Are the $Y_n$ independent?

Comment: Two of the three replies on the page you link to are explicit about their construction.  They answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between the $X$'s and the $Y$'s. In the example where the $X$'s are defined, they are constructed to be *independent*. This independence is essential in proving why there is no almost sure convergence. OTOH the $Y$'s are defined to ensure pointwise convergence occurs almost everywhere.

It is true that the $X$'s and $Y$'s have the same *marginal* distribution, i.e., each $X_n$ has the same distribution as the corresponding $Y_n$. But we've just seen that it's impossible to decide almost sure convergence by the marginal distributions alone.